# Another Approach for Getting the Apex(Server side Controller) returned value in Lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

Can you tell me what are the other approaches for getting the Apex(Server Side Controller) in Lightning. The Only one i know is the **data.getReturnedValue()**. What i want is to avoid Merging the duplicate records. For Example the apex returned a list with the same element value **{marvin,marvin}**. The **data.getReturnedValue()** will return only 1 marvin. and What i want is to return all the element value eventhough there are duplicate records.

JS CLIENT SIDE CONTROLLER

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.GetallContacts");
    action.setCallback(this, function(data){
        component.set("v.events", data.getReturnValue()); ////<------------This Line I only know to retrieve the apex serverside controller returned value
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
})
```

SERVER SIDE CONTROLLER

```
@AuraEnabled
Public Static List<Contact> GetallContacts(String textsearch,String EventName,String FieldSearch){ //<----- Error points here
    List<Ticket__c> ids = TicketIDget(textsearch,EventName,FieldSearch);
    Set<String> newids = new Set<String>();
    for(integer i=0; i<ids.size(); i++)
    {
        newids.add(ids[i].Booker__c);
    }
    map<Id,Contact> cmap = new map<Id,Contact>([SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN:newids]);
    list<Contact> clist = new list<Contact>();  // changed "map" to "list"
    for(Ticket__c tc : ids){
        clist.add(cmap.get(tc.Booker__c));
    }
    return clist;
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of your getAllActiveEvents function?

Comment: Please Look at my Codes again. I already edit it so that you can understand the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the lightning component controller. The problem is with the server-side controller. If you have the same contact twice, when you put the two identical ids into a `set<>`, it will merge the duplicates. Try this instead:

```
Public Static List<Contact> GetallContacts(String textsearch,String EventName,String FieldSearch){
    List<Ticket__c> ids = TicketIDget(textsearch,EventName,FieldSearch);
    Set<String> newids = new Set<String>();
    for(integer i=0; i<ids.size(); i++)
    {
        newids.add(ids[i].Booker__c);
    }
    map<Id,Contact> cmap = new map<Id,Contact>([SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN:newids]);
    list<Contact> clist = new list<Contact>();
    for(Ticket__c tc : ids){
        clist.add(cmap.get(tc.Booker__c));
    }
    return clist;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no much idea of Lightning Components but I have tried for you, can you please give try to below code:

```
Public Static List<String> GetallContacts(String textsearch,String EventName,String FieldSearch){
    List<Ticket__c> ids = TicketIDget(textsearch,EventName,FieldSearch);
    List<String> newids = new List<String>();
    for(integer i=0; i<ids.size(); i++)
    {
        newids.add(ids[i].Booker__c);
    }

    List <Contact> listContact= [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN:newids];
    List <String> result = new List<String>();
    for(Contact c : listContact){
        result.add(c.Name);
    }
return result;
}
```

I hope above code will solve your porblem !!